# css and certain images not working in github pages

Tags: html, css, github

I am coding a newspaper website, and I want to make a directory for the articles

I have copied the code from article's to the article directory and cleared the articles out of the code to put a story in its place.

- When you load articles the css loads:
  https://reedycreektimes.com/articles
- But when you load it through article it doesn't:
  https://reedycreektimes.com/article/templte.html

Please help me: here's the repo
https://github.com/reedycreektimes/reedycreektimes.github.io

Comment: All of your paths are relative to the current folder (e.g `href="css/style.css"`). They should be absolute (e.g. `href="/css/style.css"` or `href="https://reedycreektimes.com/css/style.css"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set absolute path for your css.

```
/css/media.css
# not
css/media.css
```

The latter would work fine from the root path of the site, not from a subpath/subfolder.

---

See more with "[Understanding Why Relative Links Are Broken](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fixing-broken-relative-links-on-github-pages)" from [Benney Au](https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/benney-au)

> When you deploy to GitHub Pages, the base URL of your website has the following structure:
>
> ```
> https://{org}.github.io/{repo}.
> ```
>
> A subdomain is created for your GitHub organization and your repository's name is appended as a fixed path.
>
> This means if your GitHub organization name is "company" and your repository name is "`my-static-website`", then your website will be hosted at
>
> ```
> https://company.github.io/my-static-website.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Correct path for any file inside a source code is:-
For **CSS** - If inside the main project folder `./style.css`
If inside a styles css folder - `./css/style.css`

For **Js** - `./main.js`
If in folder - `./js/main.js`

For **Images** - `./man.svg`
If in folder - `./images/man.svg`

For Github Pages:-
There might occur a issue when you select a theme for the repo. But after proper configuration it might not be an issue.
In Pages Section go for `main branch` select for `root`.

---

Wait for 15 to 20 minutes (it might take short time too), the page will get reloaded, and the changes will take place. 
[![Github Pages][1]][1]